# Calculating weighted average of percentage values

Tags: statistics, average, percentages, means

I have total sales of each year like so:

```
2018 100$
2019 150$
2020 210$
```

I am trying to find the weighted moving average(here moving over 2 years for simplicity) of the % growth, which looks something like this :
((current year sales - previous year sales)/ previous year sales) x 100

```
2018 100$
2019 150$ 50%
2020 210% 40%
```

So, a regular average of 50 and 40 would be (50+40)/2 = 45%

I need to give the recent years more weightage, hence I want to do the following :
(0.25X50) + (0.75X40) = 12.5 + 30 = 42.5%
Is the aforementioned method correct way of finding a weighted average of percentage values ?

Comment: Yes. Weighted average means that the sum of all weights is `1` (as you do by 0.25 and 0.75)

Comment: @Ripi2 

But given that the values I am using are percentage values of different denominators. Is this still valid ?

Comment: Yes. You can apply weights to whatever you like. In fact, a "normal" average is a particular case with both weights `0.5` (same as divide by two). I don't see those *different denominators* you speak about.

Comment: @Ripi2
Sorry, I might need to phrase it better
I meant the percentages are of different numbers. 
i.e 50% refers to 50$/100$ and 40% refers to 60$/150$. I meant 100 and 150 as different denominators